# How to write a method that is generic across any number (Ordering[_]) in scala?

Tags: scala, generics

I'm trying to implement a simple method that can be applied to any number:

```
/**
 * Round `candidate` to the nearest `bucket` value.
 */
def bucketise[Ordering[A]](buckets: Seq[Ordering[A]], 
    candidate: Ordering[A]): Ordering[A] = ???
```

I don't want just parameterise totally generically since my method will use < and > comparisons. I think that means I should restrict to any `Ordering[_]` type, but I don't seem to be able to specify that.

Calling the above (or the variation where I replace `A` with `_`) gives me the following error:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(3)
 required: Ordering[_]
       NumberUtils.bucketise(List(1,2,3), 3)
```

What's the right syntax for what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I misunderstand, what you want is:

```
def bucketise[A](buckets: Seq[A], candidate: A)(implicit ev: Ordering[A]): A = ???
```

which can be written in the sugared form:

```
def bucketise[A : Ordering](buckets: Seq[A], candidate: A): A = ???
```