# How to define a function as generic across all numbers in scala?

Tags: scala, generics

[I thought](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33069586/how-to-write-a-method-that-is-generic-across-any-number-ordering-in-scala/33069638#33069638) I needed to parameterise my function across all `Ordering[_]` types. But that doesn't work.

How can I make the following function work for all types that support the required mathematical operations, and how could I have found that out by myself?

```
  /**
   * Given a list of positive values and a candidate value, round the candidate value
   * to the nearest value in the list of buckets.
   *
   * @param buckets
   * @param candidate
   * @return
   */
  def bucketise(buckets: Seq[Int], candidate: Int): Int = {

    // x <= y
    buckets.foldLeft(buckets.head) { (x, y) =>
      val midPoint = (x + y) / 2f

      if (candidate < midPoint) x else y
    }
  }
```

I tried command clicking on the mathematical operators (`/`, `+`) in intellij, but just got a notice `Sc synthetic function`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use just the scala standard library, look at [`Numeric[T]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.Numeric). In your case, since you want to do a non-integer division, you would have to use the [`Fractional[T]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.Fractional) subclass of `Numeric`.

Here is how the code would look using scala standard library typeclasses. Note that `Fractional` extends from `Ordered`. This is convenient in this case, but it is also not mathematically generic. E.g. you can't define a `Fractional[T]` for `Complex` because it is not ordered.

```
def bucketiseScala[T: Fractional](buckets: Seq[T], candidate: T): T = {
  // so we can use integral operators such as + and /
  import Fractional.Implicits._
  // so we can use ordering operators such as <. We do have a Ordering[T] 
  // typeclass instance because Fractional extends Ordered
  import Ordering.Implicits._
  // integral does not provide a simple way to create an integral from an 
  // integer, so this ugly hack
  val two = (implicitly[Fractional[T]].one + implicitly[Fractional[T]].one)
  buckets.foldLeft(buckets.head) { (x, y) =>
    val midPoint = (x + y) / two
    if (candidate < midPoint) x else y
  }
}
```

However, for serious generic numerical computations I would suggest taking a look at [spire](https://github.com/non/spire). It provides a much more elaborate hierarchy of numerical typeclasses. Spire typeclasses are also specialized and therefore often as fast as working directly with primitives.

Here is how to use example would look using spire:

```
// imports all operator syntax as well as standard typeclass instances
import spire.implicits._
// we need to provide Order explicitly, since not all fields have an order. 
// E.g. you can define a Field[Complex] even though complex numbers do not 
// have an order.
def bucketiseSpire[T: Field: Order](buckets: Seq[T], candidate: T): T = {
  // spire provides a way to get the typeclass instance using the type 
  // (standard practice in all libraries that use typeclasses extensively)
  // the line below is equivalent to implicitly[Field[T]].fromInt(2)
  // it also provides a simple way to convert from an integer
  // operators are all enabled using the spire.implicits._ import
  val two = Field[T].fromInt(2)
  buckets.foldLeft(buckets.head) { (x, y) =>
    val midPoint = (x + y) / two
    if (candidate < midPoint) x else y
  }
}
```

Spire even provides automatic conversion from integers to `T` if there exists a `Field[T]`, so you could even write the example like this (almost identical to the non-generic version). However, I think the example above is easier to understand.

```
// this is how it would look when using all advanced features of spire
def bucketiseSpireShort[T: Field: Order](buckets: Seq[T], candidate: T): T = {
  buckets.foldLeft(buckets.head) { (x, y) =>
    val midPoint = (x + y) / 2
    if (candidate < midPoint) x else y
  }
}
```

Update: spire is very powerful and generic, but can also be somewhat confusing to a beginner. Especially when things don't work. Here is an [excellent blog post](http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/demystifying-spire) explaining the basic approach and some of the issues.

Comment: OK thanks I'll check out spire. The thing is that the scala docs for Int (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Int) don't list the traits it extends so I ended up guessing about `Ordering`. How can I find out what traits `Int` extends so that I could have found `Numeric[T]` for myself?

Comment: @jbrown Ordering is a [typeclass](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/06/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-12-type-classes.html). Typeclasses do not work using inheritance.

Comment: So how could have known, by looking at the docs, which typeclasses apply to Int?

Comment: You can't. Int does not know which typeclasses are defined for it. That is the beauty of typeclasses, but it also makes it somewhat harder to discover them. When working with spire, you just choose the simplest typeclass you need for your computation (e.g. if you only need addition, use [AdditiveSemigroup](https://github.com/non/spire/blob/master/core/shared/src/main/scala/spire/algebra/Additive.scala) instead of Field) and then check in the console whether there exists an instance for the concrete types you are interested in.

Comment: :-/ that's a bit annoying. I understand why `Int` might not know, but I'd have thought there would be a function that could scan the namespace or something and find out what typeclasses a type is a member of. Otherwise you "just have to know" which seems a bit pointless.

Comment: Anyone could define a typeclass for any type, so the issue becomes what instances for this typeclass exist in my current scope. Implicit resolution is used to find them, so the same rules apply. Also, a type is not a 'member of' a typeclass, a typeclass instance exists for a particular type. This sounds nitpicky, but it's actually an important distinction

Comment: Is there no function that will tell me what's in scope at the point of invocation? E.g. if I set a breakpoint where I wanted to know what implicits could be found for a certain type, and so what typeclasses exist for the type, could I run a certain function that would tell me "Int has typeclass instances for X, Y, Z, etc"?

Comment: Usually you have to at least know which typeclasses you want to use. Then you can find out which instances are available on the console by asking for an instance with `implicitly`. E.g. `implicitly[Field[Double]]`. I can see why what you are asking for would be useful, but it does not exist.